# Multiple calls to same Meteor method in for loop

Tags: angularjs, meteor

Use Meteor and AngularJS, I have the following setup:

**ctrl.js**

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    Meteor.call('serverMethod', arg1, arg2, function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

**methods.js**

```
'serverMethod' (arg1, arg2) {
    return HTTP.call("GET", "http://example.com/foo/var");
}
```

With the aim being that, for each element in result, it would call the Meteor method on the server, which would make a HTTP GET request, returning some data and then logging that data.

This all works, however it is doing it one at a time (make request, wait for result, make next request). I thought this would all run asynchronously?

What have I missed here/ what can I improve?

Comment: Just to add some explanation to Derrick's answer below: You're right to expect this to run asynchronously in the general sense, however Meteor queues subscriptions and method calls on the server and processes them in order so the method callbacks on the client will be called in that same order, even though they are technically asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this.unblock(); inside your meteor method [here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-unblock-and-defer-in-methods) is a page for more info.

Comment: Thanks @derrick, this helps a lot!